# How to use Apache to serve Django server and React client?

Tags: django, apache, reactjs, deployment

I'm trying to configure Apache2 to serve Django for backend APIs (`/api/`), and React app for client side JS (`/`).

I want the root path to load the React app (e.g. `www.example.com/`).

I'm having a hard time. If I Alias/Documentroot the `/` to React's `/build` directory, then Apache stops serving Django. And conversely when I remove the Alias/Documentroot, then Django serves fine but React doesn't. How could I do this?

Here's my httpd.conf file:

```

```
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/project/webapp/build/
Alias / /home/ubuntu/project/webapp/build/
<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/webapp/build>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /static /home/ubuntu/project/webapp/build/static
<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/webapp/build/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess server python-home=/home/ubuntu/python3.5/ python-path=/home/ubuntu/project/server
WSGIProcessGroup server
WSGIScriptAlias /admin /home/ubuntu/project/server/server/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/server/server>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the other way,
did you refer this ? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use virtual host ? so set 1 port to serve the backend and another port to server the frontend. 
i also use apache httpd to server django & react apps, you can check my httpd.conf & httpd-vhosts.conf here [Apache mod_wsgi django enable multi-thread multi-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852894/apache-mod-wsgi-django-enable-multi-thread-multi-process/49855203?noredirect=1#comment86755489_49855203)

I have question, are you really want to serve both backend & frontend using same apache instance ? or you will have 2 instance / service for backend and frontend, so when one apache httpd server going down, that won't inflicting the other.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, delete the DocumentRoot and the first Alias and Directory that lead to the `build` folder. Those are not needed. You only need the Alias and Directory that leads to the static folder inside build.

You will also need to make sure that Django knows where to find your React static files. I have already configured an app using this technique. Please see my post about this exact topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215233/how-can-i-have-django-serve-react-using-apache2-on-ubuntu-18-04/64215980#64215980)