# deploying a Python Flask project with Apache + mod_wsgi on Windows 11, encountering an import error when trying to import the paddleocr module

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi, windows-11, paddle-paddle

The following are the detailed information：

1. apache : 2.5.4(win64)
2. mod_wsgi : 4.9.2
3. python : 3.10
4. paddlepaddle-gpu : 2.6.0.post116
5. paddleOCR : 2.7.0.3
6. YoloV5：5.7.0
7. torch：2.0.1+cu117

apache errors：

```
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\mytest\\mytest.py", line 10, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     from IDCARD import main\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\mytest\\IDCARD.py", line 2, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     from paddleocr import PaddleOCR\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\paddleocr\\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     from .paddleocr import *\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\paddleocr\\paddleocr.py", line 21, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     import paddle\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\paddle\\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     from .base import core  # noqa: F401\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\paddle\\base\\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     from . import framework\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\paddle\\base\\framework.py", line 37, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     from .. import pir\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\paddle\\pir\\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     from . import core  # noqa: F401\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\paddle\\pir\\core.py", line 23, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     from ..base import unique_name\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\paddle\\base\\unique_name.py", line 17, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     from .wrapped_decorator import signature_safe_contextmanager\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]   File "D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\paddle\\base\\wrapped_decorator.py", line 17, in <module>\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460]     import decorator\r
[Wed Feb 21 17:19:52.818357 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 32384:tid 1308] [client ::1:10460] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decorator'\r
```

Previously, there was a similar import error issue with MarkupSafe, which was resolved by re-downloading Ninja. However, upgrading paddlepaddle did not resolve the issue.
I have added   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}  to the httpd.conf  but do not work

ps：
I have re-downloaded the packages involved in the previous errors, and those issues are resolved.when I try to import torch, it's giving me an error.

```
[Thu Feb 22 15:47:11.908299 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 30800:tid 1260] D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\pkg_resources\\__init__.py:2870: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('google')`.\r
[Thu Feb 22 15:47:11.908299 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 30800:tid 1260] Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages\r
[Thu Feb 22 15:47:11.908299 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 30800:tid 1260]   declare_namespace(pkg)\r
[Thu Feb 22 15:47:11.915273 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 30800:tid 1260] D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\rec_ID_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\pkg_resources\\__init__.py:2870: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('zope')`.\r
[Thu Feb 22 15:47:11.915273 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 30800:tid 1260] Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages\r
[Thu Feb 22 15:47:11.915273 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 30800:tid 1260]   declare_namespace(pkg)\r
```

I have downgraded setuptools to version 67.6.1, but the error still persists, and I'm puzzled why a mere warning would cause a wsgi error.

Comment: Seems like a broken package to me. Could you uninstall and reinstall the package once.

Comment: Appreciate for your response, but I have re-installed PaddleOCR and still encounter the same issue. Should I re-download other packages as well?@ShubhamS

Comment: Please confirm that the mod_wsgi is using the same env that your flask is using (the conda env that I see in logs). Check that "WSGIPythonHome /path/to/your/virtualenv" is the case for you in http.conf.

Comment: Yes. Thank you again. I previously added WSGIPythonHome "D:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/rec_ID_gpu" to the http.conf file, which is an environment created by Anaconda. However, it didn't work. Now, I have added PYTHONHOME to the Windows environment variables and pointed it to the aforementioned file path. Additionally, I have re-downloaded the packages involved in the previous errors, and those issues are resolved. But now, when I try to import torch, it's giving me an error.@S_s

Comment: I have a feeling that wsgi and flask are resolving to two different python versions. Please refer to this once - https://serverfault.com/questions/969780/import-error-on-deploying-a-flask-app-on-apache. It's for linux based system but you can implement something similar to confirm this once.

Comment: I have update Apache and mod_wsgi 
Apache:2.4.55（httpd-2.4.55-o111s-x64-vs17）
mod_wsgi:5.0 
It works, but the stress test results don't show much improvement compared to just using Flask on its own.@S_s

Comment: Well, performance is a different subject altogether. Flask by default runs on a single thread and putting it behind mod_wsgi wont magically speed it up. I believe you want to be able to increase the number of requests you are able to serve in a given timeframe. Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852894/apache-mod-wsgi-django-enable-multi-thread-multi-process)