# How can I have Django serve React using Apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: reactjs, django, apache, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to deploy a Django application with a React frontend using Apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04. The React application is being served by Django through the `staticfiles` app. For context, let's start off with how Django is serving React.

The following code is from `nerd-rich-django-back-end/nerdrich/urls.py`.

```
from homepage.views import index
url_patterns = [
    path('', index, name=index),
]
```

Next we have `nerd-rich-django-back-end/homepage/views.py`

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
index = never_cache(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='build/index.html'))
```

With this configuration Django will serve the React application when the user hits the root endpoint. This works in development, but when I try to replicate this in production I run into some problems. Namely...
Here is the site I am using in Apache2 -
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf`

```
<Directory /home/jakuta/.venv/bin/djangoprojects/nerd-rich-django-back-end/nerdrich>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
<Directory /home/jakuta/.venv/bin/djangoprojects/nerd-rich-django-back-end/nerd-rich-front-end/build>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The DocumentRoot directive was deleted and the Django application works fine **as there are other endpoints to test like the API endpoints using DRF**.
But when a request to https://nerdrich.net/ is made, there is only a blank page. If you navigate to https://nerdrich.net/jakuta you will get the browsable API.

For additional context, here are some of the settings in Django
`nerd-rich-django-back-end/nerdrich/settings.py`

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000'
    'http://localhost:5000'
] # used in development -- not sure how to use in production since Django now serves React

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'nerd-rich-front-end')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': # the default Options are set here
    }
]
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'nerd-rich-front-end', 'build', 'static'),
)
```

Again, requests made to native Django endpoints work fine, but when the html page from the build version of React is requested the page is blank. Please let me know if there is any additional information needed I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I left out of the Apache config, namely, since I already have SSL configured through LetsEncrypt, here is what I needed to add to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf`

```
Alias /static /home/jakuta/.venv/bin/djangoprojects/nerd-rich-django-back-end/nerd-rich-front-end/build/static
<Directory /home/jakuta/.venv/bin/djangoprojects/nerd-rich-django-back-end/nerd-rich-front-end/build/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Apache must be configured to serve React's static files in the `build/static` folder. Otherwise, React will not work.